# can't see data injected to a TableView object but can select it

Tags: javafx, fxml

don't really know what's the issue here..
UI is created using JavaFX Scene Builder...
I'm using Cell Value Factory to populate TableView component with data inside Controller object:

```
final ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Product("milk UHT 3,2%", "2", "3,55"),
                new Product("milk UHT 3,2%", "2", "3,55"),
                new Product("milk UHT 3,2%", "2", "3,55"),
                new Product("milk UHT 3,2%", "2", "3,55"),
                new Product("milk UHT 3,2%", "2", "3,55")

        );

        productNameColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("description"));
        productQuantityColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("quantity"));
        productPriceColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("price"));

        receiptTable.setItems(data);
```

Here's my property object:

```
private class Product{
        private SimpleStringProperty description;
        private SimpleStringProperty quantity;
        private SimpleStringProperty price;


        private String getDescription() {
            return description.get();
        }

        private SimpleStringProperty descriptionProperty() {
            return description;
        }

        private void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description.set(description);
        }

        private String getQuantity() {
            return quantity.get();
        }

        private SimpleStringProperty quantityProperty() {
            return quantity;
        }

        private void setQuantity(String quantity) {
            this.quantity.set(quantity);
        }

        private String getPrice() {
            return price.get();
        }

        private SimpleStringProperty priceProperty() {
            return price;
        }

        private void setPrice(String price) {
            this.price.set(price);
        }

        private Product(String name, String quantity, String price) {
            this.description = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.quantity = new SimpleStringProperty(quantity);
            this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
        }
    }
```

After launching it i'm getting table filled with invisible data :)
I can select it but can't see nothing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhFxD.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Getter and Setter of your `Product` class  are private. The Getter of `Product` must be `public`.

```
private class Product{
        private SimpleStringProperty description;
        private SimpleStringProperty quantity;
        private SimpleStringProperty price;


        public String getDescription() {
            return description.get();
        }

        private SimpleStringProperty descriptionProperty() {
            return description;
        }

        private void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description.set(description);
        }

        public String getQuantity() {
            return quantity.get();
        }

        private SimpleStringProperty quantityProperty() {
            return quantity;
        }

        private void setQuantity(String quantity) {
            this.quantity.set(quantity);
        }

        public String getPrice() {
            return price.get();
        }
```

Comment: the problem was that I was using an inner class. After separating it from the Control it run properly

Comment: It does not matter if the class is an inner class or not. If the Getter is private the PropertyValueFactory will not call it to retrieve the value.